# I open my application from source control, but 2 of the projects are not locked

Tags: tfs

I opened my application from source control, but Solution Explorer shows that 2 of my projects (SCD4.Model and SCD4.Repository) are not locked in. I cannot find a way to fix this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Select the project that needs to be bound to source control.
Then select File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control

Then bind in the missing items.